# ec2 stop working aws suddenly

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2

I create t2.micro EC2 instance Amazon Linux AMI, then start to upload my work on it, I'm using WordPress. it's was working perfectly but just after I Install "woocommerce" & "woocommerce subcribe" plugins, the instance stopped working I can't log using FileZilla or SSH. If I disassociate and Re-associate the Elastic IP address to EC2 instance and reboot the instance start working. but when I try to test the "woocommerce" plugin by buying a product in my website, the instance fall again. The CPU Utilization of the instance doesn't go high than 30%

Comment: Is the instance behind AWS ELB or auto scaling group

Comment: Sorry I'm new on this thing, if you ask if I use Load Balancer, yes, when the instance fall I see the "HTTP ERROR 503" in browser, as  I know it's related SSL issue but I don't understand why the instance fall down too

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your comment

> I see the "HTTP ERROR 503" in browser

So if you see 503 then it means the server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the server. Check if anything is causing it to be in some infinite loop or getting it stuck for some resource. But in this case I would primarily doubt the application rather than the infrastructure